# Slim, OAuth 2.0, андройд приложение

Tags: php, oauth2, slim

Появилась необходимость сделать регистрацию и авторизацию для андройд приложения, для этих целей предполагается использование Slim и OAuth2.0 Server PHP, не имея опыта, не совсем понимаю как их скрестить, какой тип грантов из OAuth 2.0 использовать, и как вообще пользоваться OAuth server PHP в контексте Slim. Возможно некорректно поставлен вопрос, но буду благодарен за любую помощь. (Так же буду благодарен если кто разъяснит как лучше, в архитектурном плане, все это организовать).

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, пользователь будет вводить логин и пароль в приложение? OAuth свой сервер или через сторонний сервис?

Comment: Да, вводить будет в приложении, OAuth свой.

Comment: Что-нибудь типа такого https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/oauth-2-ru (в Вашем случае - явная авторизация, поскольку Вы оунер и сервера, и клиента)